# Match hashed password created by Simplemembership with password input from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption, mvvm, passwords

I have a WPF app and a MVC based website.  I want the WPF app to read the database that the MVC website created for password information to be specific the hashed password.  How do I hash the WPF password that is inputted to match the hashed password in the database that MVC created?

What I have already:

1. is a MVC based Website using EF that created
   multiple databases.
2. One of the databases has all the password information such as the
   hashed password and salt.
3. I am using Simplemembership in the MVC project.

EDIT: Originally, I did not know I needed to hash the password manually.  Thanks to the solution below, now I know.  I have not tested it yet though because I'm still creating the logic for it.

```
    [Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class Membership
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), MaxLength(128)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
I have conclude that I need to do the validation of the password on the website itself and send a boolean response back to the wpf app that verifies the credentials.  I am looking further into the issue to figure out if I need wcf or a web service to do that.

Comment: Provide more information so people can help. How are the passwords encrypted? Are the actually encrypted or hashed? What encryption or hashing algorithm your website is using?

Comment: I am using webmatrix.webdata that is in the account controller that is calling  WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName,model.Password); with simplemembership so the passwords have their own database linked to the user

Comment: I had minimal knowledge of the situation till @Leo mentioned that information.

Comment: This question is not off topic anymore and it is a good source of information for anyone having this kind of issues which we all know it's complex considering that the MS Provider Model has been poorly-designed and it's inconsistent across different ASP.NET releases. Keeping this question "off topic" would only go against the developers community.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you are using the `SimpleMembershipProvider`. By default, the passwords are hashed, which means encryption can only be done "ONE WAY", once a byte array is hashed you cannot convert it back to a plain text format.

So basically, what you need to do is retrieve the hashed password from the database and the password salt. Then hash the password provided by your `WPF` app user (which is currently in plain text using the password salt you just retrieved from the database. Here's an example...

```
    public string HashPassword(string password, string passwordSalt)
    {
        int saltSize = 128 / 8;//128 bits = 16 bytes
        int PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 256 / 8; //256 bits = 32 bytes
        byte[] salt;
        byte[] subkey;
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltSize, 1000))
        {
            salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
            subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
        }

        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[1 + saltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, saltSize);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + saltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
    }
```

This method will return the password hash that you use to validate and compare the password provided by the user against the password hash stored in the database...

```
public bool Login(string username, string password)
{
    var user = GetUser(username); //get the user from the database including the password hash and salt

    //hash the password provided in the login screen
    string pwdHash = HashPassword(password, user.PasswordSalt);

   return pwdHash.equals(user.PasswordHash);
}
```

### Edit based on further info

Ok, you've got a massive problem here. From the screenshot you provided I can see that all users' password salt are empty which might be the main source of all your problems because the passwords are hashed. I think what's causing you to send blank password salts is the mapping in your EF entity, more specifically this one line of code...

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), MaxLength(128)]
public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
```

which is instructing EF ignore blank password salts. You will need to change it to...

```
[Required, MaxLength(128)]
public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
```

but in essence you really need to read a tutorial about the `SimpleMembershipProvider` in `MVC4` so you know how to deal with other problems that might arise. Here is a good one by [Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx), please read it

Let me know if you run into any issues

Comment: I have implemented this solution but not yet tested.  I will return feedback when I do.

Comment: the hash passwords dont match :(.  I'm getting two different hash passwords

Comment: what version of MVC is your web application using?

Comment: MVC4 
I found the source code for crypto and I'm using this line `Crypto.HashPassword(password);` to hash my password and for some reason its giving me a different hashpassword everytime it is used

Comment: it's giving you a different password because you have to specify exactly the same salt value. If you use the same salt value the hash will be same. Please re-read my answer

Comment: my database's salt value is "" though, and also I dont see where I can  insert the salt anywhere in that method

Comment: Are you sure your passwords are hashed or encrypted?

Comment: to be honest I have no idea.  This is the method I traced back `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount`  

here is a ss of what the database looks like with the passwords [image of the database here](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5423/433k.png)

Comment: I can't see the column names. Are the passwords the same by any chance?

Comment: After the second Date is the salt. where its the empty cell 

yes they are because i wanted to switch between accounts easily

Comment: what's the name of this database table?

Comment: in the database its called "webpages_Membership"
in the code its referred to as "Membership
Check my original question for to look at the class of the table

Comment: I've just edited my answer

Comment: I figured out what happened...By default the salt is passed as string.empty to the table to be more secure.  I probably has to just save the salt somewhere else then call it back to hash the passwords on the wpf side

Comment: @imGreg, can you remember how you solved the problem. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Simple membershipProvider actualy use salted hash. But the salt is grounded in the hash value. The password can be hashed by **System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.HashPassword(password)** and can be compared with plain password string through **System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashed, password)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Client application services to do that; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)